# No data displayed

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

I am trying to display data, sent from an `.ashx` file in JSON format, using `jsrender`. How do you convert data in a `List<>` collection to JSON in `ashx` file and render it in the client using `jsrender`?  Here is the code I am using:

Handler(.aspx) file:

```
List<repo1> listRec = new List<repo1>();

OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (dr.Read()) {
   repo1 objRec = new repo1(dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1));
   listRec.Add(objRec);
}
String ex = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(listRec);
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.Write(ex);
```

Client side:

```
function getDetails(va){
    $.ajax({
        url: "bll_data.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                 
        data: { "ex": va, "method": '3' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: displayReport,
        error: OnFail
    });            
}
function displayReport(dataobt){  
    $("#exg").html($("#ExgTemplate").render(dataobt));
}
```

if I can get the `dataobt` in this format in client side:

```
[{ ecode: "1", "ename": "xxxx" },
        { ecode: "2", "Name": "yyyy" },
        { ecode: "3", "Name": "zzzz" }
]
```

The displayReport(dataobt) function [will work](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/11/09/goodby-jquery-templates-hello-jsrender.aspx) the output( `alert(dataobt);` ) I am getting now in the client side is a series of "[object Object],[object Object]...". I think objects are being added to the `List<>`.

Conversion at the client side is where I think the problem is.

Can someone please correct the code?

Comment: what is the output of bll_data.ashx when you hit it directly with a web browser?

Comment: What does ex look like after this line: String ex = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(listRec);

Comment: Hi, can you post your jsRender template "#ExgTemplate" as well?

Comment: Thanks to all. I finally got it working.Initially was getting null output for ex. so i changed the contenttype to "text".Now it displayed the data in json format.I then changed it back to application/json" and it displayed correctly.